# How To Start MariaDB And Keep it Running Centos Based Docker Image

Tags: docker, mariadb, centos7

I'm trying to create a docker file (base os must be Centos) that will install mariadb, start mariadb, and keep mariadb running.  So that I can use the container in gitlab to run my integration tests (Java).  This is what I have so far

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Install epel and java
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel wget

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 3306

# install mariadb
RUN yum -y install mariadb
RUN yum -y install mariadb-server
RUN systemctl start mariadb
ENTRYPOINT tail -f /dev/null
```

The error I'm getting is
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Comment: Only an idea: Could you use this https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/ad6b97a27e6c09b81fb8d1e091b276b8ca5fff76/10.4/Dockerfile as a roadmap?

Comment: Did you mount the volume claim to your host's cgroup? Why would you use both CMD and ENTRYPOINT? And why using Dan Walsh's outdated proposal to run systemd anyway?

Comment: Any reason not to use the premade image? https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/mariadb-102-centos7

Comment: This is my first time using docker.  If I use the premade image I don't know how to run it as root and install java on it

Comment: You almost always run your application and database in separate containers.  Conversely, you almost never run systemd in a container (it tries to manage a great many things that Docker and your host already manage, and it makes it difficult to diagnose what your process is actually doing); just run the database as a foreground process.

Comment: @DavidMaze i get that you "almost" always run your database and application separately but for the few use case for running both in the same container how is mariadb supposed to be started?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
FROM centos/mariadb-102-centos7

USER root
# Install epel and java
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel wget

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/
```

You can mount your code folder into this container and execute it with docker exec.

It is recommended however you use two different containers: one for the db and one for your code. You can then pass the code container the env vars required to connect to the db container.

Answer (score 0):

nothing is running by default in containers including systemd so you cannot use systemd to start mariadb

if we reference [the official mariadb dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/ad6b97a27e6c09b81fb8d1e091b276b8ca5fff76/10.4/Dockerfile), we can find that you can start mariadb by adding `CMD ["mysqld"]` to our dockerfile.

you must also make sure to install mariadb in your container with `RUN yum -y mariadb-server mariadb-client` as it is not installed by default either